# связи таблиц в mysql

Tags: mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin, связи, таблицы

[image: scheme]
На ERD-диаграмме часть схемы моей бд.

**Вопросы:**

1. Как в MySQL сделать составной первичный ключ, атрибуты которого подтягиваются из 2 таблиц(таблица reports).
2. Поправьте, если не прав: при такой связи, когда я удалю какую-то запись из таблицы accounts/lessons, все записи таблицы reports с удаленными значениями тех таблиц удаляться в след за ними? Если нет, скажите как это реализовать.
3. Тот же вопрос для, только для таблиц answers и questions.

Если какой-то отчет удаляется, хочу чтобы записи ответов к этому отчету тоже стирались.

Я думаю по структуре примерно понятно что я хочу. Есть некий набор видеоуроков с вопросами к каждому из них(разного кол-ва могут быть). И есть отчеты с ответами каждого пользователя к конкретному уроку. Вообще прокомментируйте структуру таблиц\связей. Правильно ли вообще спроектировал?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. ```
   CREATE TABLE reports (
     account_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
     lesson_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
     `datetime` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
     checked BOOLEAN,
     PRIMARY KEY (account_id, lesson_id),
     CONSTRAINT fk_reports_account_id FOREIGN KEY (account_id)
       REFERENCES accounts (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
     CONSTRAINT fk_reports_lesson_id FOREIGN KEY (lesson_id)
       REFERENCES lessons (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
   )ENGINE=InnoDB
   ```
2. Зависит от того, что вы укажете в секции `ON DELETE` ключа. Допустимые значения

   - `CASCADE` — дочерняя запись удаляется при удалении родительской
   - `SET NULL` — ссылке присваивается значение `NULL`. Если у самого поля стоит атрибут `NOT NULL` то при удалении родительской записи возникнет ошибка
   - `RESTRICT` или `NO ACTION` — удаление родительской записи невозможно, пока на нее есть ссылки

И помните, в MySQL внешние ключи поддерживают только движки `InnoDB` и `NDB` версии 7.3 и выше. Остальные оператор `FOREIGN KEY` проглотят, но создадут обычный индекс